# OpenLayers vector layer is not clipped by extent parameter

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to limit rendering of a vector layer to a bounding box, but the `extent` property on [ol.layer.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) does not change the geographic bounds of what is rendered in the vector layer.

Here is a simple example:

```
  var base = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.TopoJSON(),
      url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/quizzicol/7068241/raw/4f6ced3a2412a48141843bee07f6ae2034eea21b/world110.json'
    }),
    extent: [-180, 0, 180, 70]
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [base],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 1
    })
  });
```

And here it is in action: http://codepen.io/mikeskaug/pen/XKOGLN. I expected this to limit rendering to objects in the northern hemisphere, yet the entire world is still rendered.

What am I missing? I'm using OpenLayers 3.17.1

Comment: You would have to reproject the extent (eg `ol.proj.transformExtent([0, -45, 90, 45], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')`), but it still does not clip the layer. Could you please open an issue? https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues